# Is it possible to calculate the power from a mixed-effects logistic regression model with a ordinal outcomes, when you have only odd ratios, n and alp

Tags: r, logistic, ordinal-data

I want to calculate the power of a mixed-effects logistic regression model with a ordinal outcomes from a study I want to replicate.

I have alpha, the n and odd's ratio.
Do anyone know r-package for this? I use to use 'clmm' but they do not have any power analyses.

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Have you tried the `simr` package ?